# Learning locker LRS communication authentication

Tags: lrs, learning-locker

I have created a LRS server and created a client in Learning Locker.
When a new client is created username and password is auto generated. But for LRS communication (statements) we need auth code. In docs its not specified to generate auth token for api access. If anyone is familiar with the Learning Locker please help me.

Comment: Faced the same problem, but I was helped by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63606746/i-always-get-401-unauthorized-response-with-xapi-for-learning-locker-using-commu/63635912#63635912)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass with the header (Also see Apache is not stripping your authorization header)

```
Authorization Basic base64(your_secrect_usernmae:your_secrect_password)
```