# I always get 401 unauthorized response with xAPI for Learning Locker using community EC2 AMI machine

Tags: lrs, xapi, learning-locker

I've configured Learning Locker on AWS EC2 and using the already build community AMI with Ubuntu 16.04. I can access the URL and can login into the system and play with it. I went in and created the client and using the default organization.

I'm passing Authorization token as per documentation in my each of the request but I still get 401 unauthorized.

I even followed the support videos that are shared in the documentation for statements and state but they even didn't work for me.

I'm sturggling on this from two days now, so assistance is required. I tried it using CURL and using Insomnia software but the response remained same. As I'm under test settings, so don't mind even sharing the exact tokens. And CURL requests.

Here is the CURL request that I used

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic NDk0MTdjYmUzMDQ3YzkyOWJkOTIzMWUxOWM2YmYwZjZhNzMyMmE0YTpjMzYyZWFlYTU5ZjgwMjAxY2VjYjQ4NjIxY2EyMGQ2NmIwNmU4ZDE4" -H "X-Experience-API-Version: 1.0.3" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://ec2-18-185-127-9.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/data/xAPI/activities/state --data "activityId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.org%2Factivity&agent=%7B%22mbox%22%3A%20%22mailto%3Atest%40example.org%22%7D&stateId=example_state_id&registration=361cd8ef-0f6a-40d2-81f2-b988865f640c"
```

Here is the response: `{"errorId":"7fe46a1d-e46e-4a22-ad21-399c6bb16e6a","message":"Unauthorised"}`

The only call that succeeds is call to `/data/xAPI/about`, which gives the below response

```
{
"X-Experience-API-Version": "1.0.3",
"version": [
"1.0.3"
]
}
```

**Learning Locker Status**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-77:~$ sudo su learninglocker
learninglocker@ip-172-31-33-77:/home/ubuntu$ pm2 status
┌─────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name         │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ API          │ default     │ 2.0.0   │ cluster │ 1501     │ 47h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0.3%     │ 105.7mb  │ lea… │ enabled  │
│ 3   │ Scheduler    │ default     │ 2.0.0   │ cluster │ 1949     │ 47h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 78.0mb   │ lea… │ enabled  │
│ 1   │ UIServer     │ default     │ 2.0.0   │ cluster │ 1502     │ 47h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0.3%     │ 80.2mb   │ lea… │ enabled  │
│ 2   │ Worker       │ default     │ 2.0.0   │ cluster │ 1910     │ 47h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0.3%     │ 106.3mb  │ lea… │ enabled  │
│ 4   │ xAPI         │ default     │ 0.0.0-… │ cluster │ 1978     │ 47h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 70.9mb   │ lea… │ enabled  │
│ 5   │ xAPI         │ default     │ 0.0.0-… │ cluster │ 2027     │ 47h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0.3%     │ 71.6mb   │ lea… │ enabled  │
└─────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

**Learning Locker Logs**

```
learninglocker@ip-172-31-33-77:/home/ubuntu$ pm2 logs xAPI
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [xAPI] process (change the value with --lines option)
/var/log/learninglocker/xapi_stdout-4.log last 15 lines:
4|xAPI     | 2020-04-22 10:28:57:549 - info: Listening on port 8081
4|xAPI     | 2020-04-22 10:28:57:553 - info: Process ready
4|xAPI     | 2020-04-22 10:28:57:600 - info: Created new Mongo connection
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 12:13:23:946 - info: Listening on port 8081
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 12:13:23:952 - info: Process ready
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 12:13:24:008 - info: Created new Mongo connection
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 19:57:44:805 - info: Created new Mongo connection

/var/log/learninglocker/xapi_stdout-5.log last 15 lines:
5|xAPI     | 2020-04-22 10:28:59:426 - info: Listening on port 8081
5|xAPI     | 2020-04-22 10:28:59:429 - info: Process ready
5|xAPI     | 2020-04-22 10:28:59:468 - info: Created new Mongo connection
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 12:13:23:943 - info: Listening on port 8081
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 12:13:23:952 - info: Process ready
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 12:13:24:014 - info: Created new Mongo connection
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 20:11:38:514 - info: Created new Mongo connection
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-27 15:01:13:192 - info: Created new Mongo connection

/var/log/learninglocker/xapi_stderr-5.log last 15 lines:
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:06:39:195 - error: 17200f4e-d98d-48ba-b09b-ea447fa68b05: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:14:59:778 - error: e9ae78fd-943a-4647-b310-ad101ba913d4: xapi-statements handled - Method (undefined) is invalid for alternate request syntax
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:42:05:999 - error: 078ef7b8-b33b-4280-8565-747994ed1e73: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:56:08:157 - error: c6a21e87-1215-4b04-91dd-b510b52d6364: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:02:50:626 - error: fd56c95b-b9c5-4178-8d18-6f35141490d6: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:03:25:201 - error: 1b38c501-449a-411e-a347-4dc9b2d642ca: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:11:56:776 - error: 651244b9-31ee-437c-abf5-7dbf2210e2a4: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:12:18:698 - error: d6cd8b7a-bd15-4692-84df-a5f3c3ec9b9f: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:13:04:239 - error: e9a37180-da2e-456b-8408-92817f78c9e3: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:24:04:922 - error: 7fe46a1d-e46e-4a22-ad21-399c6bb16e6a: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:33:49:707 - error: 49c9671e-b029-408b-8b81-cfcd38308fdb: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:46:18:820 - error: 4955d956-8b33-4be6-b3bd-3931f9249bae: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:49:33:257 - error: 4f0fadbf-122e-4412-8967-c5995bf74b35: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 23:48:56:248 - error: ed0c1692-f6b2-4190-9645-d09389c9cf9b: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
5|xAPI     | 2020-08-27 15:01:13:225 - error: 32028e87-e844-4a01-8136-a6a2a2ee53b9: jscommons handled - Unauthorised

/var/log/learninglocker/xapi_stderr-4.log last 15 lines:
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:08:32:861 - error: 4311e4ac-bdcd-4765-98db-a9292e8d921b: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:14:16:597 - error: 4a3dda4a-d5f9-49d5-b78f-1ab7b4bac731: xapi-statements handled - Method (undefined) is invalid for alternate request syntax
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:52:58:594 - error: 2dda9bd1-c1f2-4635-9ff6-f7865163824a: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 21:58:22:651 - error: f45b92c0-6403-439e-9783-0384d22a352b: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:03:16:466 - error: f4b494e2-6daf-485e-9c63-65febf4d1dab: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:11:45:122 - error: 0dcbcc49-2b69-45a2-91e8-e8d8422cbcc4: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:12:45:131 - error: d662c18e-8c0a-4efd-b3b5-9c13cc236c57: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:13:11:537 - error: da431a2c-a157-4695-a808-90381bf99113: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:25:27:984 - error: 53926e82-0d1f-45a2-8a70-f4c3b7c43e64: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:33:27:589 - error: 93e21ba1-0c06-4721-868f-6205b13a0009: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:35:41:287 - error: 7512a719-d25b-4852-a40e-9a8c6f5d2300: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 22:47:03:308 - error: 7a5aab9e-8675-4588-b720-ccf422f61f42: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
4|xAPI     | 2020-08-26 23:27:07:862 - error: c54e4396-33f3-4cfa-8141-79db6cfa130b: jscommons handled - Unauthorised
```

Can anyone tell me, what mistake I'm making over here? Please also go through the screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create at least one Store and specify it in the client settings.

1. Log into your organization.
2. Select Settings > Stores.
3. Click Add New (to add a new record store).
4. Fill in the Name/Description.
5. Then go back to your Clients menu.
6. Specify the LRS and Scope in the client details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar specifically with Learning Locker, but I don't believe the displayed value for the Authorization header is correct, at least not what I would expect it to be based on the displayed key and secret. The base64 encoded value of:

> NDk0MTdjYmUzMDQ3YzkyOWJkOTIzMWUxOWM2YmYwZjZhNzMyMmE0YTpjNDk0MTdjYmUzMDQ3YzkyOWJkOTIzMWUxOWM2YmYwZjZhNzMyMmE0YTpjMzYyZWFlYTU5ZjgwMjAxY2VjYjQ4NjIxY2EyMGQ2NmIwNmU4ZDE4

Decodes to:

> 49417cbe3047c929bd9231e19c6bf0f6a7322a4a:c49417cbe3047c929bd9231e19c6bf0f6a7322a4a:c362eaea59f80201cecb48621ca20d66b06e8d18

Which appears to have an extra segment `c49417cbe3047c929bd9231e19c6bf0f6a7322a4a`

You might try a header with the following value:

> NDk0MTdjYmUzMDQ3YzkyOWJkOTIzMWUxOWM2YmYwZjZhNzMyMmE0YTpjMzYyZWFlYTU5ZjgwMjAxY2VjYjQ4NjIxY2EyMGQ2NmIwNmU4ZDE4

Which is based on the key and secret then base64 encoded

> 49417cbe3047c929bd9231e19c6bf0f6a7322a4a:c362eaea59f80201cecb48621ca20d66b06e8d18

Comment: Thanks for responding but the extra part one token is used only in curl request, other requests are without the extra part, which can be seen from screenshots. I'm going to update the curl request too. in the question.